# Test connection to the IBM MQ server every couple of minutes

Tags: c#, ibm-mq

We are using the **IBM.XMS 8.0.0.5** .NET library to connect to the IBM MQ server and create our listeners.

But sometimes the VPN tunnel goes in sleep mode (this happens if one of our servers restarts for example). To prevent this, it is necessary to keep the VPN tunnel 'awake' by sending a network packet through the tunnel.

I looked around but IBM MQ does not have any implementation to test the connection to the server. I need some kind of 'ping' which will keep the tunnel up. But pinging is not allowed, I think they reject ICMP echos.

I am planning to create an async Task which will test the connection regularly depending on a configured interval.

Any advice on this one please?

**PS** Sometimes the connection falls asleep as I mentioned above. And without knowing anything the system engineer restarts the service which sends a `dispose` to the IBM server, even a `dispose` message leads to the connection being back up. And all items on the queue start being consumed by us while the service is being stopped... I need to solve this but I don't have a clue how I can do this.

**EDIT**

Connection is made and consumers are set up as follows:

```
var factoryFactory = XMSFactoryFactory.GetInstance(XMSC.CT_WMQ);

// Create WMQ Connection Factory.
var cf = factoryFactory.CreateConnectionFactory();

// Set the properties
cf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_HOST_NAME, _parameters.IbmMqHost);
cf.SetIntProperty(XMSC.WMQ_PORT, _parameters.IbmMqPort);
cf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_CHANNEL, _parameters.IbmMqChannel);
cf.SetIntProperty(XMSC.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, XMSC.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
cf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_QUEUE_MANAGER, _parameters.IbmMqQueueManager);
cf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.USERID, username);
cf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.PASSWORD, pw);
cf.SetIntProperty(XMSC.WMQ_CLIENT_RECONNECT_OPTIONS, XMSC.WMQ_CLIENT_RECONNECT);

// Create connection.
connection = cf.CreateConnection();
connection.ExceptionListener = ExceptionCallback;
session = connection.CreateSession(false, AcknowledgeMode.AutoAcknowledge);
destination = session.CreateQueue(queuename);
consumer = session.CreateConsumer(destination);
consumer.MessageListener = listener;
connection.Start();
```

Comment: How do you provide your app the connection details such as channel name, hostname, port?  Do you use a CCDT or some other method?  Do you know what the HBINT of the SVRCONN channel on the remote queue manager is set to?

Comment: Is this Managed .NET or Unmanaged .NET?

Comment: @JoshMc I use IBM.XMS.dll as mentioned above to make a connection to the server. I'm a client (c# console application). Connection details are given using: `var cf = factoryFactory.CreateConnectionFactory();`

Comment: My question is still the same.  You can use XMS in Managed or Unmanaged mode.  The property `XMSC_WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE` will be set to `WMQ_CM_CLIENT` for Managed mode (this is the default) or `WMQ_CM_CLIENT_UNMANAGED` for Unmanaged mode.

Comment: Did you ever get a resolution to your issue.  I was working toward an answer but just needed to understand more fully how your app was working.  MQ client v7.0 and higher connected to a MQ queue manager v7.0 and higher provide bidirectional heart beat messages when the connection is inactive.  The HBINT setting on a SVRCONN channel along with the client side setting determine how often a HB message will be set.  It will be sent if no other traffic has been sent for that number of seconds.

Comment: The running HBINT value is negotiated to the highest value between the SVRCONN and the client.  On a SVRCONN the default value is 300 seconds (5 minutes). For MQ .NET clients it is documented in the IBM Knowledge center that the client uses the value of the SVRCONN unless you use a CCDT.

Comment: I found recently two defects related to HBINT with .NET and have reported them to IBM.  1. If you do not use a CCDT, both managed and unmanaged .NET will set default client side value to 300 not matching the SVRCONN value as documented.  2. on managed .NET if your client side HBINT is less than the SVRCONN HBINT value the program will crash.  This can be with out a CCDT and the SVRCONN is set to 301 or higher, or with a CCDT if the SVRCONN is any value greater than the CCDT's CLNTCONN HBINT value.

Comment: Based on the above info if your HBINT was defaulting to 5 minutes then depending on the timeout of your VPN tunnel this could impact you.

Comment: Thanks for the info @JoshMc, Everything has the default value. So what you are saying is maybe correct. We didn't solve this issue yet. And btw, we are using managed .NET

Comment: Ask the MQ Admin to display the channel status of the running `SVRCONN` when you are connected and tell you the negotiated `HBINT` value, they can run a command like `DIS CHS(CHL_NAME) HBINT` to see this value, also ask them what they set the `HBINT` to on the `SVRCONN` itself, the command `DIS CHL(CHL_NAME) HBINT`.